# CSS Modifications Won't Work for Amazon Kindle Cloud Reader

Tags: html, css, fonts

The default font used for Kindle Cloud Reader is Georgia, and it displays horribly under the renderings of Windows ClearType. Using `@font-face` is usually an easy way to swap out a certain font family. Here, I used the CSS scripts from Google Fonts, replaced the `font-family` values in order to use Bitter instead of Georgia, and appended it to the website with User CSS Chrome extension.

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Bitter Italic'), local('Bitter-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bitter/v12/-t3SK6sofTjAH0MNf_tLaPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Bitter Regular'), local('Bitter-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bitter/v12/zfs6I-5mjWQ3nxqccMoL2A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Bitter Bold'), local('Bitter-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bitter/v12/evC1haE-MsorTl_A7_uSGVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

Similar scripts worked on countless websites. However, it doesn't work for Amazon Kindle Cloud Reader. Manually changing the font-family value inside the inspect elements tool won't work. Stylish styles or Greasemonkey scripts created to change fonts on Kindle Cloud Reader won't work either.

Can anyone try modifying the fonts within their Kindle Cloud Reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Chrome, you can get a web extension called Force Custom Fonts. I'm using it in Kindle Cloud Reader right now with my favorite typewriter font. The trick is, once you have set the font families in each of the four fields, hit Save and *close the options page.* Then when you open Kindle Cloud Reader it'll just work.